# What is the purpose of DynamoDB filter expressions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to work out what advantages there are to using filter expressions for the DynamoDB `Query` operation.

I understand that it's used to refine the results of a query, as explained here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.FilterExpression. But this also says that the same limits apply *before* the filter, so don't gain anything in terms of reduced read capacity consumption or overcoming the 1MB-per-query limit.

Why would I use this over in-built language features, like Scala's `filter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*A filter expression is applied after a Query finishes, but before the results are returned.*

So, ultimately it saves you bandwidth. Scala's filter works the same way - you create the collection first and then filter will iterate over it and filter out the results that don't match your predicate.

Spark filter operation on the other hand, is a transformation operation and is hence lazily evaluated which allows Spark to perform some optimisations.

Comment: I've a doubt here. Why can't we just add the conditions of filter in query conditions itself. Won't this be more optimized way of getting the result and how would that make any difference.

Comment: I also have same doubt as Nikhil but I believe it is because with Query, we will use attributes with indexes and then put filter on attributes without indexes. If we use attributes in query without indexes then, it will slow down. However, filtering later would not have that much impact as results are fewer.